# Should I make my answer a community wiki post?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

I think this is an incredibly handy usage of Notepad++'s macro function.  Is that criteria for making it a community wiki post?

[How do I add "input" to my macro, to replace text in Notepad++?](https://superuser.com/questions/376288/how-do-i-add-input-to-my-macro-to-replace-text-in-notepad/377642#377642)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "adding it to a wiki"? Do you want to make your answer a Community Wiki post? Do you want to add it to a tag wiki?

Comment: yeah community wiki post, slhck

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This decision is entirely up to you. Making a post **community wiki** will result [in the following](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts):

> - A much lower reputation (100 instead of 2000) is needed to edit a community wiki post.
> - Voting on a community wiki post (up or down) does not affect any user's reputation.

This might make it easier for others to edit your answer, because it's now community-owned, and they don't feel they're changing *your* answer.

There are no "criteria" for you to decide whether you need to make something community wiki.  You never have to. However, if you specifically want others to **continue improving your answer**, then by all means, make it community wiki, and leave a note for others to see. This would encourage contributions.

<sub>Note: I've made this CW myself, so we have a practical example :)</sub>

<sub>Note: And I've edited it, so there's that, I guess?</sub>